# SQL Server: display differences in columns between 2 rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a very large table (200+ columns) with 1000's of rows. I need to display differences in columns between 2 rows. I can load the 2 rows I need into a temp table, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

For example (I’ll only use 5 rows here and just use generic names)

```
ID        | GName       | SName    | Add1         | Add2
360111    | Billy       | Bob      | 1 Happy St   | Sydney
360111    | Billy       | Bob      | 6 Sunny St   | Melbourne
```

What I want to be displayed is

```
Add1       | Add2
1 Happy St | Sydney
6 Sunny St | Melbourne
```

As these are the only differences between the 2 rows. Other times there will be no difference, or many

Cheers

Comment: "I have a very large table (200+ Columns)" You have a very large problem ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: will this query always be over only two records?  If there are 500 records, do you only want to output the columns that are never repeated, or perhaps the columns that are not the same in each of the 500 rows?

Comment: I presume it's the differences between two given rows, given the wording of the introductory paragraph.

Comment: There's no way to write a static query, such that the number of output columns varies. And to write a dynamic query for this, you'd have to *already* know which columns contain differences. Perhaps a different output than the one you're asking for would be just as useful - how are you planning to consume this result?

Comment: I would think that Craig wants to see, which records with same ID have different values in some columns and because it is hard to look at 200 columns at once, he wants to see only differing columns. Guess only of course :)

Comment: Would another approach be to list all duplicate IDs? That would be a lot easier, I would think.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make some dynamic sql that will loop over the meta-data of the temp-table and will check if there is any need to return a given column. In the end, dynanically create a SELECT statement that will return the key (you can hardcode this for this situation or you can make it a parameter if you'd put this logic in more generic stored procedure).

Quick & dirty it would look something like this :

```
-- setting up test-data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #test

SELECT ID     = 360111,
       GName  = 'Billy',         
       SName  = 'Bob',       
       Add1   = '1 Happy St',   
       Add2   = 'Sydney'
 INTO #test

UNION ALL 

SELECT ID     = 360111,
       GName  = 'Billy',     
       SName  = 'Bob',      
       Add1   = '6 Sunny St',   
       Add2   = 'Melbourne'


GO
-- find different columns and list them
DECLARE @c_column_name sysname
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#diff_columns') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #diff_columns

SELECT column_name = name
  INTO #diff_columns 
  FROM sys.columns
 WHERE 1 = 2

DECLARE column_loop CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT diff_columns = name
          FROM tempdb.sys.columns
         WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#test')
           AND name <> 'ID' -- no need to test the key-field
OPEN column_loop
FETCH NEXT FROM column_loop INTO @c_column_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sql = 'INSERT #diff_columns (column_name)
                       SELECT ''' + @c_column_name + '''
                        WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #test HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT ' + @c_column_name + ') > 1)'

        EXEC (@sql)                        

        FETCH NEXT FROM column_loop INTO @c_column_name
    END
CLOSE column_loop 
DEALLOCATE column_loop 

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ID'
SELECT @sql = @sql + ', ' + column_name
  FROM #diff_columns
SELECT @sql = @sql + ' FROM #test'

EXEC (@sql)
```